# Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using symfony-6 and want have $data parameter in controller, in order to create object through Api-Platform, it gives this error in Api-Platform:

```
"Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier.\Class \"App\\Entity\\User\" does not have an identifier."
```

It is my code in controller and want to check the code through Api-Platform

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __invoke(User $data): void
    {
        print $data->getLogin() . PHP_EOL;
        print $data->getPassword();
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question lack of details, here is my best answer.
In a standard use of Api Platform you do not have to use Custom Controller to create object.
Using Api Platform 3 :

You just have to call an endpoint with method "POST" in order to create the corresponding object.

In order to do that you have to declare User entity as an ApiRessource and properly set which field can be write using "Groups".

Here is an example using Php Attribute :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')] // Do not remove ` or it will crash
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']],
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
)]
class User 
{

#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
#[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
#[Groups(['user:read'])]
private ?int $id;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
#[Groups(['user:read', 'write'])]
private string $email;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 100)]
#[Groups(['user:read', 'write'])]
private string $firstName;
}
```

Then Api platform does the magic if you call your url using method POST admitting it is

```
/api/users
```

With payload

```
{
  "email": "johndoe@email.com",
  "firstName": "Thomas"
}
```

As you can see in ApiRessource attribute, i declared group "write" in denormalizationContext.
It litterraly mean : `when creating or updating this entity i allow property with group write to be written`
Since `$id` is auto-generated, it do not need to be in group `write`

For a more precise answer please provide user entity class and api platform configuration for this entity.

If you want additionnal thing to be done uppon creating an object, for example, sending an email to the user with a invitation link. Look to subscriber.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/

Hope it helped

Comment: Yes, it is clear and thank you for your full reply. I wanted to edit POST endpoint in my code adding path, name and controller. I used to use controller in older version of symfony. It is even working in symfony 6.1.* with controller, but with version of 6.2 it gives error.

Comment: My best advise would be : never use custom controller unless needed for a specific behavior. 
For an example, i have controller for download of file since it need specific response.
For custom operation, even using not persisted object (DTO) which you can declare as ApiResource too are the greastest way to retrieve and write object.